# ActiveMQ Artemis divert to multiple addresses

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am migrating from ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis. ActiveMQ "Classic" has [composite destinations](https://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations) which can forward messages to multiple destinations.

ActiveMQ Artemis uses [diverts](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html) to forward messages. Can you have one divert to multiple addresses or do you need a separate divert config for each address you wish to forward onto ... for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you'll need an individual `<divert>` for each address where you want to forward the message.

However, in the upcoming ActiveMQ Artemis 2.21.0 you'll be able to forward messages to multiple addresses from a single divert. See [ARTEMIS-3670](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3670) for more details.

Comment: Thx Justin... Virtual topics are mapped to a Fqdn... Do I need an entry in the broker.xml for virtual topic?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't support "Virtual Topics" as such, but the fundamental semantics (i.e. send to a JMS topic & consume from a JMS queue) *are* supported.

Comment: Ok..As Artemis already uses a separate queue per topic subscriber then there is no need for a virtualtopic ... I think this is true ?

Comment: I propose that each reference in the backend to the activemq virtualtopic is now replaced with reference to the queue FQDN for implemeting artemis

Comment: When you say "FQDN" do you mean "FQQN" as noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names)? Also, I don't understand why you're making a proposal. Can you clarify this?

Comment: activemq defines a virtual topic in the activemq.xml - for artemis I need no entry in the broker.xml for a virtual topic - I just use the fqdn (as defined in documentation) to reference a virtual queue in the backend - is this correct ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question so you can explain your full use-case. These comments are meant to clarify the answer, not ask new questions. This isn't related to your original question about diverts - at least not directly. Also, you keep using "fqdn" and I'm still not sure what you mean by that (as noted previously).